# Why no append() method on Django ValuesListQuerySet?

Tags: python, django, list, append

Any good reason there is no append method on Django ValuesListQueryset ?

If  I want to add an element, is there a better way than converting first to a list ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do, why do you want to add an element?

Comment: because the queries are lazy I guess ?

Comment: yes, but why do you want to add an element? :)

Comment: django querysets are not lists.......though they still support some list operations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my comment:

> django querysets are not lists.......though they still support some list operations

Also as programmersbook commented.....[django querysets are lazy](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy) i.e. The queries are executed when the queryset is first accessed. Let us say you have chained a long filters for getting a queryset, even then the database will be hit only once, at the time of access of queryset value. 
Now let us say you have a queryset:

```
sample_set = SampleModel.objects.filter(sample_field='sample_value').filter(another_sample_field='another_sample_value')
```

The queryset returned will have a corresponding single sql query like

```
SELECT something FROM sometable 
WHERE sample_field='sample_value' 
AND another_sample_field='another_sample_value'
```

There is no way that one can achieve something like `sample_set.append(sample_object)` as sample_set represents an SQL statement.